# How to force npm using a compatible node.js version?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to clone a project available on GitHub onto a Google Cloud Platform linux instance. For this, I need to execute npm in the app folder of the project. But then I get the error message:

```
ERROR: npm v10.1.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

Hence, I tried to update node.js from the binary archive found at nodejs.org according to these instructions (the OS being Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS):

https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation#how-to-install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-linux

But when it comes to step 4. of the instructions and I execute the following commands

```
# node -v
v10.19.0

# npm version
ERROR: npm v10.1.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0.  This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

I firstly see that the node version is still v10.19.0, and secondly, I get the same error message as above, which is not surprising, since the binary archive seems to extract its content into the directory /usr/local/lib/nodej (step 1. of the instructions):

```
# mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
# tar -xJvf node-v20.11.1-linux-x64.tar.xz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
```

(I did not make use of the environment variables VERSION and DISTRO as suggested in the instructions, but specified the file name as is in the command line)

and, hence the node binary located unter /usr/bin is still the old version.

There is a binary file named node located at /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v20.11.1-linux-x64/bin, which seems to be the binary in question:

```
# /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v20.11.1-linux-x64/bin/node -v
v20.11.1
```

and I could copy this file over to /usr/bin, but I am a bit reluctant to do this, since it could be possible that there are other inconsistencies which might mess things up.

So, what is the best way to execute npm and make sure, that it uses the newer version of node?

Comment: Use a nodejs version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [volta](https://volta.sh/)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the most effective method to ensure you're using the latest version of Node.js along with an up-to-date npm version is by utilizing [Node Version Manager (NVM).](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

These are some helpful commands you can use once NVM is installed:

1. Check installed Node.js version `node -v || node --version`
2. List locally installed Node.js versions `nvm ls`
3. List available remote versions of Node.js `nvm ls-remote`
4. Install a specific version of Node.js `nvm install 18.16.1`
5. Set a default Node.js version `nvm alias default 18.16.1`
6. Switch to a different Node.js version `nvm use 18.18.2`
7. Install the latest LTS (Long Term Support) version of Node.js `nvm install --lts`
8. Install the latest stable version of Node.js `nvm install stable`